# How to Play .WAV in .Net Compact Framework (Datalogic Memor) Windows CE 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a Data logic Memor  with Windows CE 5.0 on my Applications i used only Message Box and Color Changing Labels for My Validation and Error Handling.

Now my problem is that i need to play .wav file on validation so even users do not need to look on screen every time they used the Scanner.

I tried this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229685.aspx but doesnt work..

Data Logic Memor Doesn't Have Media Player..

Thanks in Regards!

Comment: Way doesn't it work? I have used that approach a couple of times and find it quit usefull.

Comment: :) What Handheld Device you used? In this approach?

Comment: You have to define "doesn't work."  P/Invoking like the MSDN article suggests should work on any device with an audio driver.  Is your device capable of playing sounds?  Does it have more than a "beep" that might be a simple piezo?

Comment: Only Beep Sir(Data logic Memor)...It doesnt have any media player..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got The Answer on the official Data Logic Memor Support team. The Original Memor really doesnt have any capability to play other tone other than beep. Thanks in Regards for your Help!

Comment: I have a Datalogic Memor 4.10 (Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional) and it does play a .wav file using the `SoundPlayer` class, and also using the `PlaySound`-API.  (I did not try the `waveOut*`-methods.)

`datalogic.device` also seems to have a `Beeper`-class with Frequency and Time properties/parameters, but I did not get that to play anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can play a .wav file in different ways. You don't say what compact framework you use, but for CF 3.5 you have the SoundPlayer class which is fairly easy.

```
        SoundPlayer p = new SoundPlayer("path");
        p.Play();
```

If you wont to play large files and have more flexibility have a look at these API calls:

```
   waveOutWrite
   waveOutOpen
   waveOutPrepareHeader
   waveOutClose
```

There are some work to use them. The idea is to open and initiate a wav file device with waveOutOpen and then prepare a WAVEHDR and writing it to the device with waveOutWrite. More exactly how you do it you can see in this good [post](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3). Where he describes and show you the code.

Still an other way to play a wav file is to use Windows Media Player. But I have bad experience with it. If you use it, you must be very careful to uninitiate between songs. You can also use the [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Controls/MediaPlayerControls/tabid/264/Default.aspx) player or use WMP directly like a com object. If you use CF 2.0 or older you have to create you AxHost by you self.

Well I hope this helps.